# Best way to iterate through resource column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm making a list to show inputs that filter by category.
I want 6 inputs to show the categories and their icons.

I have a table called `Pin`, which has a `:category` column.

I will only have 6 fixed categories, so I guess the best way is to put them in an instance variable hard-coded as well as the icons for each category?

```
@categories = ["Lamparas","Mesas","Camas","Accesorios","Textil","Sofas"]
@categories_icons = ["svg23","svg24","svg25","svg26","svg27","svg29"]
```

In my view, I'm doing:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li class="product-list-item">
        <div class="product-tile">
            HERE GOES THE ICON
        </div>
        <%= f.radio_button :category, html_input: {type: :radio, name: "#{category}", value: "#{category}"} %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, how can I match my icons with the category when painting them on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think about this?

```
categories = ["Lamparas","Mesas","Camas","Accesorios","Textil","Sofas"]
icons = ["svg23","svg24","svg25","svg26","svg27","svg29"]
@categories_icons = Hash[[categories,icons].transpose]
```

them you can replace `HERE GOES THE ICON` with:

```
@categories_icons[category]
```

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. Awesome. Thanks!